# What are the other examples of medium-sized stars?

Tags: star, the-sun, solar-system, galaxy

Please put the light year also. Its for our report so I need some examples. I've already searched on some books but I don't find anything.

Comment: Recommend closing as unclear (undefined) what's being asked

Comment: Alpha Centauri A is only a bit larger than the Sun, as I recall.

Comment: A google search comes up with example lists. I'm not sure this is a good question here.

Answer (score 1):

1.) I think it's unclear what you're asking. Especially if you ask about the distance in light-years, then ask about the distance in light-years. Not 'light-years'.

2.) As soon as you're clear on what you're asking, you can try to look e.e. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_stars_and_brown_dwarfs). They don't list masses or sizes, but remember that most of those stars are on the main sequence, so the stellar class informs you about the mass or radius. Distances in Ly are given.

3.) To address @StephenG's comment: Yes the sun is a low-mass star, as e.e. classified on the x-axis of fig. 1 of [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/publications-of-the-astronomical-society-of-australia/article/div-classtitlethe-dawes-review-2-nucleosynthesis-and-stellar-yields-of-low-and-intermediate-mass-single-starsdiv/59DFD9C086C70D153511319ACF918A18).

Comment: I would agree that it is considered a low-mass star, but that doesn't make it smaller than average, let alone smaller than median.

Comment: @BrianTung: You need a distribution function to estimate that. But that's not the point. People, laypersons, often ask about size, when really what matters is mass. So you can suggest to them whether they want to talk about mass. If not, then you can happily provide them estimates of sizes. And this question's OP sounds like not a professional to me.

Comment: It's also not smaller than average in diameter.  But relax—I'm not criticizing your answer, just clarifying in response to Stephen's speculation that it doesn't mean it's smaller than average.

Comment: @BrianTung: Then I don't see the point posting that in my answer

Comment: I beg your pardon, I didn't mean to offend, but my comment was also in response to your observation.  You put your observation in your answer rather than a comment to his answer, and I put my observation as a comment to your answer.  I would have put it as a comment to your observation wherever you put it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like the [Solar Analog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_analog).

My impression, by the way, is that the Sun itself is not a medium sized star, but is smaller than average for stars in this galaxy.

Comment: Perhaps smaller than average (not sure about that), but larger than median.  The distribution of stellar mass is very skewed: If we restrict ourselves to the main sequence, fully three-quarters of stars are class M, and another eighth are class K.  That means the Sun (a class G2 star, on the earlier side of G) is in the top eighth by mass.

Comment: Not arguing with you, but would love a source for that for my own information, e.g. a diagram.  Thanks.

Comment: [This arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1078) suggests that the Milky Way's stellar mass is about 60 billion solar masses, which would put the Sun as above average as well as above median.

Comment: Here's a [short article](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?2001JRASC..95...32L&amp;data_type=PDF_HIGH&amp;whole_paper=YES&amp;type=PRINTER&amp;filetype=.pdf) on the above median part.